# NserviceBus input queue got exploded

Tags: nservicebus

I have a a NesrviceBus host that his job is to send HTTP request to our customers for each new incoming  MSMQ message.
Recently one customer begun to "return" HTTP timeouts, Which cause:
1) The input queue got exploded from new messages
2) starvation of all the other customers )-:

My solution is to split the host and to install new host for each customer.
Any other ideas?

Comment: You could specify an acceptable timeout for you not to be "exploded from new messages" and then catch the timeout and defer the message for a while until assuming the client would respond quicker.

And to avoid the starvation while waiting for requests you could set up the number of threads your worker is using so it processes more than one message at the time.

Comment: miracledev: post that as an answer.

Comment: Just to add to that, it will need to be a saga...

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to implement it using saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify an acceptable timeout for you not to be "exploded from new messages" and then catch the timeout and defer the message for a while until assuming the client would respond quicker.

And to avoid the starvation while waiting for requests you could set up the number of threads your worker is using so it processes more than one message at the time.